# Serializing Nones with json4s in a case class

Tags: scala, scalatra, json4s

I can't figure this out, Say I have a case class with Options in it like:

```
  case class Note(id: Int, noteA: Option[String], noteB: Option[String])
```

If I attempt to serialize it to json using json4s as proscribed by the Scalaltra guides, any Nones in my case class get removed from the output. Such that the following code

```
  protected implicit val jsonFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats

  before() {
    contentType = formats("json")
  }

  get("/MapWNone") {
    new Note(1, None, None)
  }
```

will produce an output of "{"id":1}", I'd like to have an output like: {"id":1, "noteA": null, "noteB": null}

I've written a CustomSerializer along the lines of:

```
class NoteSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Note](format => ({
     |   case jv: JValue =>
     |     val id = (jv \ "id").extract[Int]
     |     val noteA = (jv \ "noteA").extract[Option[String]]
     |     val noteB = (jv \ "noteB").extract[Option[String]]
     |     Note(id, noteA, noteB)
     | }, { case n: Note => ("id" -> n.id) ~ ("noteA" -> n.noteA) ~ ("noteB" -> n.noteB) }))
```

Which does the same thing as the default formatter.

I would think that changing the last line to this would work

```
case n: Note => ("id" -> n.id) ~ ("noteA" -> n.noteA.getOrElse(JNull)) ~ ("noteB" -> n.noteB.getOrElse(JNull))
```

but does not compile.

```
No implicit view available from java.io.Serializable => org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue
```

I'm wondering how I might do match for a Some/None in the noteA and noteB fields and return a JNull in the case of a None for either of those members.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it:

```
case n: Note => ("id" -> n.id) ~ ("noteA" -> n.noteA.getOrElse(null)) ~ ("noteB" -> n.noteB.getOrElse(null)) }))
```

patience is a virtue, just not one of mine.